# How to check whl file correctly generated

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I generated a .whl file following this link:
https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install

Now i am installing the package on my own machine to check if package is successfully installed. It installs successfully.
But the thing is when i import it, it gives, "ModuleNotFoundError" exception. 
What i want to know is that how do i verify the .whl file is correctly generated and usable?
Please Help i am stuck here for 2 days.
Here's my Setup.py file
[image]

And here's my package directory structure:
[image]

Here's output of my build script:
[image]

Here's my stacktrace of import error:
[image]

Comment: By testing it in a virtualenv, a VM, in a Docker container, a CI service, ...

Comment: Please show us the relevant information, i.e. your package/directory structure, 
 the contents of `setup.py`, and the output of `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

Comment: a wheel is just a zip file. you can look inside and can check if all the files that should be in there are actually present.

Comment: Okay, showing in a while

Comment: Added Setup.py and directory structure. Please check

Comment: _how do i verify the .whl file is correctly generated and usable?_ Usually by writing unit tests in an `src` directory layout and running the tests against the installed wheel. But the wheel is not your problem - you don't have any code in your project besides `TestFunc` which is already added to the wheel correctly. What is the full stack trace of the mentioned `ModuleNotFoundError`? Also, what is the `__init__.py` doing in the project root dir? A project root is never a python package itself.

Comment: @hoefling Import error stacktrace added also structure rectified

Comment: Please help i am stuck here.

Comment: `TestFunc` is not a module right now, it's a script and should be callable via `TestFunc` after wheel installation. Do you want to import code from it and have it as an executable script simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `TestFunc` as a script (to be run from the command line), not a module. (I bet you haven't tried `import TestFunc` without packaging things into a wheel.)

If you're trying to build a wheel that will install an importable module, you'll want to rename `TestFunc` to `TestFunc.py` (like you'd do with any old Python module!) and then use

```py
setup(
  # ...
  py_modules=["TestFunc"],
)
```

(and probably eventually `packages=...`) when your project grows, but that's beside the point)
.

If you're actually looking to have `TestFunc` being a script run from the command line, `scripts` is the right thing, but the script will have to be something your shell can understand – see [the packaging guide here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument) for the gist of it.